# Trying to return a list using Join if two columns match

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two tables, Images and Users. I want to return an Image if UserID matches with the ID from Users table. UserID is not a FK, its value is stored in the database when the photo is uploaded, along with the other properties from the model.

Here is the Join code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Image> GalleryOnProfilePage()
    {
        return (from u in db.Users
                join i in db.Images on u.Id equals i.UserID
                where u.Id == i.UserID
                select new
                {
                    ImageID = i.ImageID
                }).Select(x => new Image 
                { 
                    ImageID = x.ImageID
                }).ToList();
    }
```

For now I don't even know if this code will work and return the Image that matches my desire: `Image.UserID == Users.ID return ImageID`. I am stuck on the following error:

> The entity or complex type 'JobSite3.Models.Image' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Here is the View:

```
@model List<JobSite3.Models.Image> 

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<table class="table-striped">
    @{
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 1)
        {
            j = i;
            <tr>
                @while (j < i + 1 && j < Model.Count())
                {
                    <td>
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model[j].ImageData,0,Model[j].ImageData.Length)" width="100" />
                    </td>
                    j++;
                }
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
}
```

Thank you very much for any support

Comment: Your where clause - `where u.Id == i.UserID` seems a little suspect. You're already joining on this so this statement will always be true.

Comment: well yea, for now the code doesn't do anything anyway because breaks with that error even if I remove that line.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going one with the extra `select` and creation of an anonymous type either.

Comment: I had an annoying error. Cannot convert from AnonymousType to a list. I tried to make the page at least load and not break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ChrisF said, your are already joining according to same columns. But here your problem is not at *joining*. The exception tells that it is not possible to construct the entity itself on custom select statement. In your query you try to select new `Image` with this line of code: `}).Select(x => new Image ...`. But it is not allowed in *Linq to entities* as `Image` is entity type. You two workarounds.

### First (recommended)

As you are just selecting Id just return *list of Ids*:

```
return (from u in db.Users
    join i in db.Images on u.Id equals i.UserID
    where u.Id == i.UserID
    select i.ImageID)
    .ToList();
```

### Second

Or you can use `AsEnumerable` function to load data into memory before selecting `Image`:

```
return (from u in db.Users
    join i in db.Images on u.Id equals i.UserID
    where u.Id == i.UserID
    select new
    {
        ImageID = i.ImageID
    })
    .AsEnumerable() // Load data into memory
    .Select(x => new Image 
    { 
        ImageID = x.ImageID
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion before I made the post and it says cannot convert from `ImageID` type(my case Guid) to a list and `.ToList()` is marked with a red line. Second it returns in View `System.Collections.Generic.List1[JobSite3.Models.Image]`. I have got this output in a different way before posting the question. I am kinda in a new territory here, I don't really know how to deal with this.

Comment: @Eduard, for first you have to change return type of method to `List<Guid>`. But I ditn't understand your problem with second option.

Comment: Well instead of an Image it returns `System.Collection...`

Comment: For instance if now I just make an`Where` clause and I make something like: `x => x.UserID == User.Identity.GetUserId();` it will return an Image on View

Comment: @Eduard, but your method is supposed to return List of images. What do I miss?

Comment: I get printed out on screen that message with system.collection not an actual Image

Comment: @Eduard, I suppose you have different problem in your code which is not related to this method.

Comment: Well I made it work but it displays all Images. It doesn't select the Image with the row UserID that have the data equal with Users row ID. Here is another approach: `(from a in img from b in user where a.UserID == b.Id select a).ToList();` I select img and users with an `<IEnumerable>` then I make them lists and compare them in that line of code. When I upload an Image I save the current user logged and I when I want to display the Image I should just check if UserID from Image is equal with ID from User table, why is not working?

Comment: @Eduard, joining user table with image table according to UserID will give you all the results. I think you want to filter instead of joining. Filter data like: `from a in img where a.UserID == myUserId;`